# Python Jupyter nbconvert limiting printed pages

Tags: python-2.7, jupyter-notebook

I am running Jupyter with a Python 2.7 kernel and I was able to get 
nbconvert to run on both the command line (ipython nbconvert --to pdf file.ipynb) as well as through the jupyter browser interface.

For some reason, however, my file only prints 4 out of the 8 total pages I see on the browser.  I can convert an html preview (generated by Juypter) file, and then use an online converter at pdfcrowd.com to get the full pdf files printed.
However, the online converter is lacking in latex capability.

When I installed nbconvert, I did not manually install MikTex latex for windows, as I already had it successfuly installed for Rstudio and Sweave.
I didn't want to mess with the installation.

I printed a few longer files (greater than 4 pages), without latex and a few that had latex and printed the first couple of pages fine. But that last few pages always seem to get cut off from the pdf output.
Does anyone know if that might be causing it to limit the print output, or any other ideas why?

Also, I do notice the command line prompt where jupyter is launched has a few messages...

```
1.599 [\text{feature_matrix}
                            ] =
?
! Emergency stop.
<inserted text>

1.599 [\text{feature_matrix}
                            ] =

Output written on notebook.pdf (r pages)

[NbConvertApp] PDF successfully created
```

I ran another file and saw the output showed

```
!you can't use 'macro parameter character #,' in restricted horizontal mode.
...ata points }}{\mbox{# totatl data points}}
?
! Emergency stop
```

Look like it is somehow choking on using the latex character # 
then halting publishing. But it at least publishes all the pages prior to the error and emergency stop.

While not a solution, I manually changed the latex symbol # to number and
the entire file printed. I wonder if this is a problem with my version of latex maybe?

halted pdf job

$$\mbox{accuracy} = \frac{\mbox{# correctly classified data points}}{\mbox{# total data points}}$$

passed pdf job

$$\mbox{accuracy} = \frac{\mbox{number correctly classified data points}}{\mbox{number total data points}}$$

edit: if it help anyone, I used the suggestion [here](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues/9004), to use a backslash escape character before the #, to solve the issue; so it looks like it is a latex issue, if that helps anyone.